# How to support 2 finger pinch/zoom gesture from precision touchpad in a .net wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, windows-10, multi-touch

I have .net code for a WPF app that recognizes two finger pinch to zoom or rotate and translate manipulations but only when running on a PC with a multi-touch screen (Win10 Pro 64bit Microsoft Surface), not a touchpad which is what I am trying to support. My development machine (Win10 Pro 64bit Dell Inspiron 7577) has a "precision touchpad" that supports up to 4 finger gestures. Any web browser I run on this machine responds to 2 finger zoom requests, even the VS2017 IDE itself responds to two finger zoom/scroll requests. None of the Main window touch event callbacks are executed. The code I referred to is basically listing 6.7 From Adam Nathans' WPF 4.5 Unleashed book converted to VB.net. I have also been trying to implement Florian Rappls' "Another WPF only way" approach described here [WPF and multi-touch](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692286/WPF-and-multi-touch) however the WndProc() is never called. Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Update - WndProc() is now being called. Now trying to figure out how to recognize two finger pinch to zoom touchpad gesture. Hard to believe this is so simple and elegant in Wpf via touchscreen manipulations and MatrixTransform but difficult with touchpad interactions...